# Phone gap Web-view camera not working?

Tags: android, cordova, webview, camera

I installed Phonegap..from [this](http://phonegap.com/install/) and created android app...

So in that.. at `index.html` I have added a `camera` from `web-view` with [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html)...

here I replaced `index.html` content with `Full Example's... index.html`.... from the above link..

and I have added permission for camera in `manifest` and `config.xml`..

But its not working... I have done this in android studio...

cant any one suggest me...

**Update:**

after Installing Phonegap

I have done this..

```
C:user.... : phonegap create my-app
C:user.... : cd my-app
C:user.... : phonegap run android
```

I opened that android project under my-app\platforms.. directly to Android Studio I got this...

[image]

so I skipped this step in camere...

[image]

I dont know where Should I run this.. command... And I have given all permissions according to [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html) tutorial except... above command...

can any one suggest me what should and where should I run this command I am using windows 10..

Comment: its not working on click... camera is not opening...

Comment: check in console what is the exact error!!!

Comment: there is no error that on-click is not running... camera is not working... I think I have missed this one.... But I dont know where to do.... ` $ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
    $ cordova plugin ls
    [ 'org.apache.cordova.camera' ]
    $ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.camera`

Comment: Can you please share the complete software stack/version, so that we try the same thing on our landscape

Comment: I am using android studio v 1.5.1.. today I have downloaded Phonegap I mean installed Nodejs and Replaced that index.html with camera index.html in android studio... but when I click on any button its not opening camera I have given permission also... But I dont know how to use cordova plugin org.apache.cordova.camera.. where should I need to Use this...

Comment: did you install that plugin?

Comment: When I install the latest Phone gap.. I got Cordova Lib in my Android studio...